# How to display fetched data of a database through a class function

Tags: php, mysql, function, class, fetch

I am new to OOP and want some help  I have this some code that selects and fetches data from a database but I don't know how to display fetched data.

```
/**
 * Connect to mysql database
 *
 * @return bool;
 */
public function Connect() {
    $settings = database_settings();
    $connect = new mysqli($settings->host, $settings->user, $settings->password, $settings->database);
    if (!$connect->connect_errno) {
        return $connect;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
/**
 * Prepare a mysqli query
 *
 * @return bool;
 */
public function statement($query) {
    if (!empty($query)) {
        $this->query = $query;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Execute a mysqli query and store result in memory
 *
 * @return bool;
 */
public function execute() {
    $this->database = $this->Connect();
    if (isset($this->query) && !empty($this->query)) {
        $this->database->set_charset("utf8");
        $this->exe = $this->database->query($this->query);
        if (!isset($this->exe)) {
            throw new DatabaseException("{$this->database->error} \n {$this->query} ");
        }
        if (isset($this->database->insert_id)) {
            $this->last_id = $this->database->insert_id;
        }
        unset($this->query);
        $this->database->close();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Prepare a query to select data from database
 *
 * @params = array();
 *           $params['from'] = names of table
 *           $params['params'] = names of columns which you want to select
 *           $params['wheres'] =  specify a selection criteria to get required records
 *
 * @return bool;
 */
public function select($params, $multi = '') {
    if (is_array($params)) {
        if (!isset($params['params'])) {
            $parameters = '*';
        } else {
            $parameters = implode(', ', $params['params']);
        }
        $order_by = '';
        if (!empty($params['order_by'])) {
            $order_by = "ORDER by {$params['order_by']}";
        }
        $where = '';
        if (isset($params['wheres']) && is_array($params['wheres'])) {
            $where = implode(' ', $params['wheres']);
        }
        $wheres = '';
        if (!empty($params['wheres'])) {
            $wheres = "WHERE({$where})";
        }
        $limit = '';
        if (!empty($params['limit'])){
            $limit = "LIMIT {$params['limit']}";
        }
        $query = "SELECT {$parameters} FROM `{$params['from']}` {$wheres} {$order_by} {$limit};";
        $this->statement($query);
        if ($this->execute()) {
            return $this->fetch($multi);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Fetch the data from memory that is stored during execution;
 *
 * @params = $data = (ture if you want to fetch all data , or flase if only one row)
 *
 * @return bool;
 */
public function fetch($data = false) {
    if (isset($this->exe)) {
        if ($data !== true) {
            if ($fetch = $this->exe) {
                return arrayObject($fetch->fetch_assoc());
            }
        }
        if ($data === true) {
            if ($fetch = $this->exe) {
                while ($all = $fetch->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $alldata[] = arrayObject($all);
                }
            }
            if (isset($alldata) && !empty($alldata)) {
                return arrayObject($alldata);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

then i select data but can't display them:

```
$params['from'] = 'category';
$params['order_by']= 'id';
$params['wheres'] = 'active="1"';
$params['limit']= '1';
$connect->select($params);
```

Comment: The same way you'd display any variable? I'm not sure what the problem is here, but it doesn't sound like it relates to this database class in any way. Or is the problem that you can't get the stored data out of memory?

Comment: i fetch the data but dont know how to access them out of function